# Open Unreal 5 editor menus make my mouse lag

Tags: unreal-engine5

When I interact with Unreal 5.0.3 main menus or short menu the mouse become very laggy and the editor sometimes crash, is there a solution to this ? I tried disabled all startup apps but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue has been resolved by turning off the automatic hiding of the taskbar.

Comment: Nice but I will move unreal to secondary monitor instead of seeing taskbar taking useless space

Answer (score 0):

I found strange result I have two monitors one is AOC VA and the other is Benq IPS both are QHD 144hz but when I move the editor to Benq monitor, my main monitor, the problem appear but when I move the editor to AOC the menu respond normally dont know why !!